# Another proof of Archimedean property (Question)

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Suppose that for each $x>0$ there exists a $n$$\in$$\mathbb{N}$ such that  $\frac{1}{n}$$<$$x$.

Give a proof of Archimidian Property using this assumption

My idea was the following:

Let given $y$$\in$$\mathbb{R}$ such that $y>n$. Then $\frac{1}{y}$$<$$\frac{1}{n}$. So, $\frac{1}{ny}$$<$$\frac{1}{n}$.

Then, because our assumption is that for each $x>0$ there exists a $n$$\in$$\mathbb{N}$ such that  $\frac{1}{n}$$<$$x$, we have $\frac{1}{ny}$$<$$x$.

That means $\frac{1}{n}$$<$$xy$.

Then, we have $n>\frac{1}{xy}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\frac{1}{xy}\in\mathbb{R}$

Then, for all $k=\frac{1}{ny}\in\mathbb{R}$, there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n>k$.

Honestly, I do not feel well with my proof and I need some orientation for improve.

My question is that I think I’m not consider all reals because $y>n$ and also, I assume each number real $k$ can be written in the form $\frac{1}{p}$ where $p\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: What does the Archimidian Property says?

Comment: You are right to question your argument. When you say "Given 
such that >" you are essentially assuming what you should prove. Start with "Given , how can I find an  such that n > y?: See if you can use what you are told to do that

Comment: @CameronBuie Yes thanks. I fixed the typo by deleting the old comment and reposting the correction.

Comment: @EthanBolker yes, I want to proof that

Comment: @azif00 Archimedean Property says that $\mathbb{N}$ has not upper bound. That means that there not exists $y\in\mathbb{R}$, such that $y>n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, or (which is the same), for all $y\in\mathbb{R}$ there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $y<n$

Comment: @RicardoMejíasConstanzo Hint: what does the hypothesis tell you about the number $1/y$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption is this:

> For each $x>0$ there exists $n \in \Bbb N$ such that $1/n<x$.

And you want to prove this:

> For each $y \in \Bbb R$ there exists a natural number greater than $y$.

So, the first thing you need to do is to start with $y \in \Bbb R$, right? Note that if $y \leq 0$, then $1$ is a natural number greater than $y$, and this finish the proof in this case.

But what happens if $y>0$? Here, $1/y>0$, and so the assumption says that there exists $n \in \Bbb N$ such that $1/n<1/y$. Thus, $n$ is a natural number greater than $y$, finishing the proof in this other case.